# How could I make this into a regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to make this "ServerLog(07-05-2013@22-07)" into a regex.

```
my $filename = q{ServerLog((\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)@(\d+)-(\d+))};
```

This is what I have but it doesnt work. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Would this work?

```
my $filename = q{ServerLog\((\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)@(\d+)-(\d+)\)};
my $log = "<D:\\ServerTools\\Logs\\$filename";
my $ref = tie *FH,"File::Tail",(name=>$log);
```

Comment: is `$filename` the name of variable *containing* the regex, or are you trying to match `$filename` against the regex?

Comment: The name of the variable containing the regex is in a directory.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the first and last parentheses with a `\` since you want them to match actual parentheses in your string:

```
/ServerLog\((\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)@(\d+)-(\d+)\)/
```

like this:

```
my $string = 'ServerLog(07-05-2013@22-07)';

if( $string =~ /ServerLog\((\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)@(\d+)-(\d+)\)/) {
  print "matches";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should space out complex regex by using the /x switch:

```
my $server_log_qr = qr{
        ServerLog
        \(
        (\d{2})     # capture month
        \-
        (\d{2})     # capture day
        \-
        (\d{4})     # capture year
        \@
        (\d{2})     # capture hour
        \-
        (\d{2})     # capture minute
        \)
    }msx;

my $example = 'ServerLog(07-05-2013@22-07)';
print "$example\n";

my ( $month, $day, $year, $hour, $minute ) = $example =~ $server_log_qr;
print "month  = $month\n";
print "day    = $day\n";
print "year   = $year\n";
print "hour   = $hour\n";
print "minute = $minute\n";
```